# How to add $USER inside of nested quotes?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a variable:

```sh
my_var="$('/some/path/to/username/more/path' 'and/something/else')"
```

and I want to change it to be more generic like:

```sh
my_var="$('/some/path/to/${USER}/more/path' 'and/something/else')"
```

but that doesn't work. How can I get the user inside of there?

Comment: `my_var=$("/some/path/to/${USER}/more/path" "and/something/else")` The outer quotes aren't necessary but the inner ones are if the args contain whitespace that should be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that inside a single quoted string nothing is treated with a special meaning. This makes them good for scripting, eg. `grep '^pattern$' ...` and `sed 's/abc$/def/'`.

You can use double quotes instead.

`$(...)` is a command substitution. Is that correct? If so, then you can nest double qoutes:

```
my_var="$("/some/path/to/${USER}/more/path" 'and/something/else')"
```

This should be interpreted as two set of quotes, so the outer double quotes, isn't stopped at the first inner quote:

```
my_var="$(                                                      )" # First set of quotes
          "/some/path/to/${USER}/more/path"                        # Second set of quotes
```

When assigning a variable, you don't need to wrap the expression in double quotes, so:

```
my_var=$("/some/path/to/${USER}/more/path" 'and/something/else')
```

would also be fine in this case. Most other cases you should always wrap parameter expansions (`$abc`), command substitutions (`$(...)`) etc. in double quotes as to avoid word splitting and pathname expansions.

However to me it seems like you are trying to create an array instead?

```
$ my_var=("/some/path/to/${USER}/more/path" 'and/something/else')
$ echo "${my_var[0]}"
/some/path/to/and/more/path
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am not sure if it will work though? Basically I want to change what Conda injects: `__conda_setup="$('/Users/username/miniforge3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"` and I am not sure removing the outer quotes or using double quotes twice will work